# podman machine cannot mount folder on Fedora

Tags: fedora, podman

I am trying to create local podman machine `podman machine init` and I want to mount `/tmp:/tmp` but when I try to run like this `podman machine init -v /tmp:/tmp` but I have this error `Error: unknown shorthand flag: 'v' in -v` but when I check the podman site [podman docs](https://docs.podman.io/en/latest/markdown/podman-machine-init.1.html) and `podman version 3.4.7`
what am I doing wrong

Comment: The online man pages are probably for a more recent version of Podman. I have podman 3.4.7 installed locally, and if I look at `podman --help` or at the install man page (`man podman-machine-init`, neither suggests that there is a `-v` or `--volume` option.

Comment: @larsks It's in Podman 4

Comment: Question: do you need `podman machine`? That's generally required only on Mac...

Comment: @mattdm yes, that's what I meant by "a more recent version of podman" :)

Comment: @larsks I was juts being more specific. :)